# Handling cancellation on a wizard page

Tags: qt

I suspect that I am trying to bend a `QWizardPage` to do more than it is supposed to which is why I am running into issues but maybe there is a way to do this.

So, I have a number of pages within a `QWizard` and on one certain page I run a series of tests against some hardware that then stores results in a database. I want to be able to cancel if necessary. However at the moment the Cancel button is part of the QWizard so i am not sure how to handle it.

I am aware I can overide the `reject()` function of `QWizard` and then determine the current page and if it is the page I am interested in then do something but I would rather not tie the pages togehter in this way unless I have to.

I did try to connect the `rejected()` signal to the wizard like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(rejected()), ui->runTestPage, SLOT(on_rejected()));
```

But this instantly closes the page anyway before I can display anything back to the user to say I am cancelling.

I could add a button to the wizard page that will display when the test is running to allow a cancel but then the page still has the main cancel button. In fact even after the test is complete the Cancel still displays so being able to remove or disable that would seem appropriate.

So is this something I can do or do I need to revisit the entire use of a wizard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's doable. First you don't necessarily need to override `rejected()`, I'd go down the route of getting rid of the `QWizard` cancel button and instead insert your own `QPushButton` (or whichever) pointing to your own slot, do your 'cancelling now' message box from there and then trigger the `rejected()` slot.

It'll save you a lot of headaches from massaging the default signal/slots, and allow you to replace 'Cancel' with 'Close' which possibly makes more sense in the context of a wizard (depending on the wizard, functionality etc etc).

Comment: Thanks for that. It sounds a good option although the more I bend what the wizard does the more I think I could have done this by creating my own wizard and something like a stacked widget instead :) But this is useful learning for me anyway

Answer (score 5):

One way is to disconnect the wizard's `reject()` slot from the `cancel` button's `clicked()` signal and then connect your own slot from where you ask the user if he's really sure, like this:

In your wizard's constructor:

```
// install a slot handling the cancel button, but disconnect the default slot that would close the wizard first
disconnect( button( QWizard::CancelButton ), SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( reject() ) );
connect( button( QWizard::CancelButton ), SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( cancelWizard() ) );
```

Then implement your own slot handling cancellation:

```
void SetupWizard::cancelWizard() {
    if( QMessageBox::question( this, trUtf8( "Quit Setup" ), trUtf8( "Setup is not complete yet. Are you sure you want to quit setup?" ), QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::No ) == QMessageBox::Yes ) {
        // allow cancel
        reject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `reject` method in your wizard class and call `QWizard::reject` in your `reject` method.

```
void MyWizard::reject()
{
    if( QMessageBox::question( this, trUtf8( "Quit Setup" ), trUtf8( "Setup is not complete yet. Are you sure you want to quit setup?" ), QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::No ) == QMessageBox::Yes ) {
        // allow cancel
        QWizard::reject();
    }
}
```